# How to save a dask series to hdf5

Tags: python, hdf5, dask

Here is what I tried first

```
df = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(dict(x=np.random.normal(size=100), 
y = np.random.normal(size=100))), chunksize=40)

cat = df.map_partitions( lambda d: np.digitize(d['x']+d['y'], [.3,.9]), meta=pd.Series([], dtype=int, name='x'))
cat.to_hdf('/tmp/cat.h5', '/cat')
```

This fails with `cannot properly create the storer...`

I next tried to save cat.values instead:

```
da.to_hdf5('/tmp/cat.h5', '/cat', cat.values)
```

This fails with `cannot convert float NaN to integer` which I am guessing to be due to `cat.values` not having nan shape and chunksize values.

How do I get both of these to work? Note the actual data would not fit in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=np.random.normal(size=100),
                       y=np.random.normal(size=100)))
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, chunksize=40)

cat = ddf.map_partitions(lambda d: pd.Series(np.digitize(d['x'] + d['y'], [.3,.9])),
                         meta=('x', int))
cat.to_hdf('cat.h5', '/cat')
```

You were missing the `pd.Series` wrapper around the call to `np.digitize`, which meant the output of `map_partitions` was a numpy array instead of a pandas series (an error). In the future when debugging it may be useful to try computing a bit of data from steps along the way to see where the error is (for example, I found this issue by running `.head()` on `cat`).